# No viable overloaded operator[] for a const type

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I have a type `BigInt` which stores large numbers as an array of digits (0-9) in a char array called privately `m_digitArray`.
I was trying to overload the array access operator `[]` and it worked, both for accessing and assigning char values.

I then tried to overload the assignment operator `=`, it gave me the above-mentioned error.

Where am I going wrong? How can I transfer (essentially copy) values from one `BigInt` object to another?

Here's the code

### BigInt.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BigInt{
private:
    // Object Data
    char *m_digitArray;
    unsigned int m_digitArraySize;
    bool m_isPositive;

    // Private Methods
    int getNumOfDigits(int number);
    void reverseArray(char arr[], int start, int end);

public:
    // Constructors
    BigInt();
    BigInt(int numOfDigits);
    BigInt(const BigInt &bi);
    BigInt(const string &number);

    // Access
    int getSize() const;
    bool isPositive() const;
    char &operator [] (int);
};
```

### BigInt.cpp

```
int BigInt::getSize() const {
        return m_digitArraySize;
    }

    bool BigInt::isPositive() const {
        return m_isPositive;
    }

    char & BigInt::operator [] (int i){
        if(i > m_digitArraySize-1){
            cerr << "Error: Array index out of bounds!" << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        return m_digitArray[i];
    }

    BigInt & BigInt::operator = (const BigInt &rhs){
        if(this != &rhs){
            m_digitArraySize = rhs.getSize();
            m_isPositive = rhs.isPositive();
            m_digitArray = new char[m_digitArraySize];
            for (int i = 0; i < m_digitArraySize; ++i){
                m_digitArray[i] = rhs[i];
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

### Error

`BigInt.cpp:129:25: error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const BigInt'
                        m_digitArray[i] = rhs[i];
                                          ~~~^~
BigInt.cpp:114:16: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type
      'const BigInt', but method is not marked const
char & BigInt::operator [] (int i){
               ^
1 error generated.`

Comment: Error is quite clear, isn't it? You need to have two overloads of `operator[]` - one that is const and one that isn't. They usually have the same body.

Comment: Helpful reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading Of immediate interest is **Array Subscripting** about 1/5 of the way down the page.

Comment: @DeiDei Not really. Here the message is even clearer: `BigInt.cpp:114:16: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const BigInt', but method is not marked const` -> since the method doesn't change anything, just mark it as const.

Comment: @BenSteffan I wouldn't want the `const` operator to return `char&` and allow changing the object.

Comment: Not Quite @BenSteffan . The function returns a non `const` reference, allowing the caller to modify the object's state after the call to `operator[]` through the reference. You really do need both.

Comment: @user4581301 Indeed, that was stupid of me.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! Got it working. I will post the answer momentarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @DeiDei for pointing out I needed two separate overloads. I guess I was misreading the error prompt.

Fixed it by adding this to the header file:

```
char operator [] (int) const;
```

and this as the implementation:

```
char BigInt::operator [] (int i) const{
    if(i > m_digitArraySize-1){
        cerr << "Error: Array index out of bounds!" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    return m_digitArray[i];
}
```